# Why my vps server is taking too long to respond?

Tags: centos7, vps

I have a vps server with centos 7 with webuzo cpanel. the server seems to work fine and i get access to webuzo cpanel. But when load the page to start the wordpress installation i get the server error the website took too long to respond.

I have used the the website "downforeveryoneorjustme.com" it seems that the website is down for everyone.

I have reintalled centos 7 several times rebooted the server and reset the firewall as many times, but did not help.

Hostinger says that the permissions are messed up and that´s why the website is not loading.

Is there someone that can help, that knows what the problem is, I willing to pay small fee.

Answer (score 0):

If your site takes time to load initial files then load faster the whole site.
There might be a CPU stealing.

Or the whole site takes time to load then check the logs located at:

```
/usr/local/apps/nginx or apache/logs/SITENAME.err
```